# PDO WHERE LIKE and foreach avoiding duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables '**subscribers**' and '**status**'. I like to send status messages to the subscribers but only when they subscribed to that service.

table '**subscribers**' contains:

```
id | mail | service (comma separated)
-----------------------------------------------
1 | name1@gmail.com | TV, Internet 
2 | name2@gmail.com | Cloud, Internet 
3 | name3@gmail.com | Phone, Cloud
```

table '**status**' contains:

```
id | title | message | service (comma separated)
------------------------------------------------------
1 | Disruption | TV services offline | TV
2 | Maintenace | All services offline | TV, Internet, Cloud 
3 | Disruption | Some services offline | TV, Internet
```

**My Code:**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM status WHERE id = '2'"); // send message 2
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

$array = explode(", ", $row->service);

foreach ($array as $value) {

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE service = ? OR service LIKE ? OR service LIKE ? OR service LIKE ?");
    $stmt->execute(["$value","$value,%","%$value, %","%, $value"]);
}
```

**My problem:**

When a status message has more than one service, the subscriber get the same message multiple times. How can I avoid that? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: just as a note, it's more efficient to have your prepare statement outside the foreach, just execute inside the foreach

Comment: The better way is to not have CSV values in a single column. You should probably have a table containing a list of the services available, then add link tables between that and your `subscribers` and `status` tables.

Comment: First thing you should do is normalize your table

Comment: Thanks. I will normalize the tables first